# How to prove reverse of DFA?

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

How does one formally prove that, given a DFA $M=\langle Q,T,\delta,q_0,F\rangle$, the following NFA $M^R = \langle Q_R, T, \delta_R, q_R, F_R\rangle$ recognizes the reverse of M's language?

We build $M^R$ like this:

- $Q_R = Q \cup \{q_R\}$, where $q_R$ is a new state which will be the start state of $M_R$
- $F_R = \{q_0\}$
- $\delta_R(q, a) = p \Leftrightarrow \delta(p, a) = q$
- $\delta_R(q_R, \epsilon) = p \Leftrightarrow p \in F$

I want a formal proof that $L(M)^R = L(M^R)$.

Comment: Induction on the length of the input is probably a good start.

Comment: Thanks @rici. I tried that, but I think I did it wrong, trying to prove by induction directly that $L(M)^R = L(M^R)$. I'll try first with $\hat{\delta}(q, w) = p \Leftrightarrow \hat{\delta_R}(p, w^R) = q$ and then use that to show the equality of the languages.

Comment: sounds about right